# Spans not stacking in the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add 3 spans in the same line but they keep taking up all the width of the page each and ending up in different lines.

This is the code and below is the style:

```css
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .info-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 280px;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
    <span class=info-container>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot-text">Test</div>
    </span>
    <span class=info-container>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot-text">Test</div>
    </span>
    <span class=info-container>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot-text">Test</div>
    </span> 
  </div>
```

I've tried with the `image-container` as both `<div>` and `<span>` but neither works. Dot and dot-text have `100px` of both height and width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `display: inline-block`

[Read more here about the display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```css
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.info-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 280px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block; // <-- This
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
    <span class=info-container>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot-text">Test</div>
    </span>
    <span class=info-container>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot-text">Test</div>
    </span>
    <span class=info-container>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot-text">Test</div>
    </span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use divs inside the span they will still be shown as `display: block` so the span will still be full width. So changing the inner divs to span will fix that. Or you can use `display: inline-block` on the outer one.

```css
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .info-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 280px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block; // this can work
    }
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
    <span class=info-container>
        <!-- using spans here will also work -->
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot-text">Test</span>
    </span>
    <span class=info-container>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot-text">Test</div>
    </span>
    <span class=info-container>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot-text">Test</div>
    </span> 
  </div>
```